# "Unable to Download App", but can install through Xcode

Tags: ios

I have a Xamarin.iOS app which is available to download from our company enterprise store. Upon trying to download and install this app on iOS versions 8.2 and 9.3, it gets about 2/3 of the way complete then gives the error message, "Unable to Download App, AppName could not be downloaded at this time.".

The app downloads and installs fine on iOS 11.4 fine. (These are the only devices I have available to test).

I'm able to download other apps which are hosted on this store, so it's not a connectivity or firewall issue.

Since it installs fine on 11.4, it doesn't seem like an issue with the provisioning profile.

I can download on Mac the IPA file which is hosted, and can install this on all the devices through Xcode and it works fine.

Rebooting devices, cleaning the solutions and re-publishing have not worked, and despite connecting devices to the Console there doesn't seem to be any error message thrown.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: My first thought on this would be an incompatible iOS version. Do you have access to the app and Xcode to check it hit is compatible?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean - I can install the app through Xcode on all the versions of iOS. Could you elaborate on how else I could use Xcode to check compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. Clicking on the link in the enterprise store would point to a plist file which would then point to the download package. In the plist file, there was also a reference to the app icon which had a different file name. This meant that on lower versions of iOS it would look for that icon but would not find it. But when directly installing the IPA through Xcode, it didn't use that plist file so would download and install fine.

I don't know why this only affected lower versions of iOS, but in searching for a solution I must have filtered some relevent results out by using those search terms. Thankfully, a whole 3 weeks later and it's finally sorted!